# Why class-only protocol does not satisfy AnyObject constraint in protocol extension where clause?

Tags: swift, inheritance

I defined protocol:

```
protocol MyProtocol: class {   
}

class MyClass: MyProtocol {
}
```

And extension only for collections with class elements:

```
extension CollectionType where Generator.Element: class {
    func someFunc() {
    }
}

var items = [MyClass]()
items.someFunc() // someFunc is available

var strings = [String]()
// strings.someFunc() is not available because String is not class
```

But this does not compile and I changed extension definition to:

```
extension CollectionType where Generator.Element: AnyObject {
...
}
```

It also does not compile because `MyProtocol` does not conform to `AnyObject`.
So I changed definition of `MyProtocol` to:

```
protocol MyProtocol: AnyObject {   
}
```

It also does not compile with message:

> Type 'MyProtocol' does not conform to protocol 'AnyObject'.

Comment: `extension Array where Element: AnyObject { }` *does* compile for me. But how is that related to `MyProtocol`?

Comment: @MartinR Sorry, I updated question with more details.

Comment: What does `extension Collection` mean? Do you mean `CollectionType`? Is this your real code????

Comment: @matt Sorry, I did not copy code from Xcode playground and made a mistake when was typing code.

Comment: @MartinR Yes, it's similar question but I have found answer that does not relate to difference between class-only protocol and protocol extended from `AnyObject`.

Comment: @mixel: Yes, I just saw your answer and have therefore deleted my comment. I *think* that I have seen that question ("protocol does not conform to itself") before, but I haven't found it, so I may be wrong.

Comment: @MartinR Moreover, protocol does not conform to protocol it inherits from. That's a strange compiler behavior. I hope it will be fixed.

Comment: @mixel If you have a use case, definitely file a bug report with Apple! Nothing will change all by itself...

Answer (score 0):

After a little research I found [here](https://forums.developer.apple.com/message/15955#15955) that protocol type can not conform to protocol:

```
extension CollectionType where Generator.Element : First {
    func someFunc() {
    }
}

protocol First {

}

protocol Second: First {
}

var items = [Second]()

items.someFunc() // Type 'Second' does not conform to protocol 'First'
```

So the real issue in my case is not that class-only protocol does not satisfy `AnyObject` constraint but that protocol type can not conform `AnyObject` protocol or any other protocol.